# How to fill missing residues in multiple chains with MODELLER?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, modeling

### Question background.

I'm currently working on a project for my degree in biomedical informatics and for that I'm trying to model a specific protein with MODELLER but it's been a struggle.

All the learning resources about MODELLER are identical copies of its tutorials and the documentation is... complicated.

### What is my problem?

Right now, I have a protein with 6 chains (being A = D, G = H and B = E). There are missing residues on chains A, D, G and H; and missing atoms on chains G and H.

I was successful on filling the missing residues by aligning chain by chain like this:

To make the alignment files

```py
# ...
for chain in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'):
    model = Model(env, file='6aee', model_segment=(f'FIRST:{chain}', f'LAST:{chain}'))
    aln.append_model(model, align_codes=f'6aee{chain}_miss', atom_files='6aee.pdb')
    aln.append(file=f'6aee{chain}.ali', align_codes=f'6aee{chain}')
    aln.align2d(max_gap_length=50)
    aln.write(file=f'6aee{chain}_fill.ali', alignment_format='PIR')
    aln.clear()
```

resulting files like this:

```
>P1;6aeeA_miss
structureX:6aee.pdb:2:A:+275:A::: 3.30: 0.22
--SHSMRYFSAAVSRPGRGEPRFIAMGYVDDTQFVRFDSDSASPRMEPRAPWVEQEGPEYWEEETRNTKAHAQTD
RMNLQTLRGYYNQSEASSHTLQWMIGCDLGSDGRLIRGYERYAYDGKDYLALNEDLRSWTAADTAAQISKRKCEA
ANVAEQRRAYLEGTCVEWLHRYLENGKEMLQRADPPKTHVTHHPVFDYEATLRCWALGFYPAEIILTWQRDGEDQ
TQDVELVETRPAGDGTFQKWAAVVVPSGEEQRYTCHVQHEGLPEPLMLRWKQ*

>P1;6aeeA
sequence::: :: :::-1.00:-1.00
MGSHSMRYFSAAVSRPGRGEPRFIAMGYVDDTQFVRFDSDSASPRMEPRAPWVEQEGPEYWEEETRNTKAHAQTD
RMNLQTLRGYYNQSEASSHTLQWMIGCDLGSDGRLIRGYERYAYDGKDYLALNEDLRSWTAADTAAQISKRKCEA
ANVAEQRRAYLEGTCVEWLHRYLENGKEMLQRADPPKTHVTHHPVFDYEATLRCWALGFYPAEIILTWQRDGEDQ
TQDVELVETRPAGDGTFQKWAAVVVPSGEEQRYTCHVQHEGLPEPLMLRWKQ*
```

Then I automodel chain by chain with this:

```py
# ...
for chain in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'):
    a = AutoModel(env, alnfile=f'6aee{chain}_fill.ali', knowns=f'6aee{chain}_miss', sequence=f'6aee{chain}')
    a.starting_model = 1
    a.ending_model = 1
    a.make()
```

**How do I do it all at once or join my separate chains into the complete protein?**

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)